# Redux state shape for an entity that has list views and detail views

Tags: javascript, redux, state, single-page-application

For my entity `Car`, I have a list view that fetches all the cars from the API and renders their `make` and `year`. However, the API *only* returns these fields on the list view page. When the user clicks on one of the list items, they then go to the detail page for that car, where they get more information, such as `description`, `color`, `price`, etc.

What is the recommended approach for managing this data in Redux? One possibility is that there exists a single `state.cars` property, under which all car data exists, e.g.

```
state.cars = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    make: "Toyota",
    year: 1994
    color: "Red"
    ...
  },
  2: ...
}
```

In the above example, `1` and `2` are the ids from the database. This seems like the logical way to go, but how do I manage the fact that on the list view I don't get all the data I ultimately want for each car? Would my state initially just contain the `make` and `year` for each car, and then I'd modify those individual entries each time a user goes to a detail page?

For example, on the list view page, it would look like:

```
state.cars = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    make: "Toyota",
    year: 1994
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    make: "Honda",
    year: 1994
  },
  ...
}
```

And then if the user clicked on the second item, the state would end up looking like:

```
state.cars = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    make: "Toyota",
    year: 1994
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    make: "Honda",
    year: 1994,
    color: "Blue",
    description: "Awesome car!",
    price: 9500
  },
  ...
}
```

This seems like a good approach because it maintains a single source of truth for the car data. The downside is that now the data I have available for each car might be different. This will add greater complexity to my components, and probably create some Flow type pain.

The alternative would be to have separate pieces of state for the list view and detail data. But this would result in duplicate data in the store.

Is there a recommended approach for handling this type of problem?

Comment: At the end of the day _it depends_. How are you going into the details? Are you opening a pop up kind of thing, where your original component the `list` view is still visible in the background, and the `detail` view is layered on top of it, displaying just a single car's information? And what's wrong with having all the data but not using it in the `list` view? Do you think this is a loading/speed problem or something else?

Comment: On mobile, only the detail view will be visible. On desktop, the list view will still be visible, with the detail adjacent. I can't have all the data in the list view because of API constraints.

Comment: By API constraining you, do you mean you can't get the `details` data as well? Because if that's the case, then if you're going to show an adjacent component when you hit `details` you could just pass the id of the car as a prop and have it ajax the data then.

Comment: Correct, not until the user navigates to the detail page. I can't depend on an API that lets me just grab all data at once. It needs to be loaded on an as-needed basis.

Comment: I don't feel like there's a need to store the `details` data into the redux state, since it's ad-hoc. Just passing it via props, which then the `details` component loads the data via ajax seems to simplest. Unless there's a reason for you to hold onto the `details` data in the redux state.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however I'm hoping to provide instant rendering when going back to a detail page that has already been visited, while requesting updates from the API in the background. For that reason, the detail data needs to be stored in the state tree. As the app grows, I imagine there will be other reasons to want the detail data in the state tree as well.

Comment: well, I guess if you wanted the information inside the state then you'd have to update the redux state. Otherwise maybe create the details component if there's `detail` data, and have the ability to show/hide it instead. So something like `{this.state.x.details && <Details data={this.state.x.details} />}`  and having a button which then show/hides it or something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the approach you're talking about is called "normalization", and is the recommended approach.  See [the Redux FAQ entry on storing relational data](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data), the [Structuring Reducers - Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) docs page, and the [Redux Techniques#Normalization](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#selectors-and-normalization) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links) for more info on the topic.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with those Redux docs. The thing they don't address is the issue of having different degrees of data, i.e. the partial data I have for each car when on the list view, and then the full data I get for an individual car when I visit a detail view.

Comment: Well, there's two basic approaches.  You either have separate slices for "basic" and "detailed" data, or one slices where the items get updated as needed.  I personally would go for one slice.